# Rotating character in relation to First Person camera? (Unity3D, Pictures linked)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue where my character is facing 90 degrees away from the (first person) camera. So when I move the character, the model is turned 90 degrees to the right instead of facing forward. [(Pic 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPcrj.jpg)

Since the camera is a child of the player, if I rotate the character -90 degrees, the camera rotates with it. If I rotate my camera back 90 degrees, the controls get messed up (the W to go forward becomes W to go right, etc.) [(Pic 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFkTb.jpg)

Is there anything I can do to either change the default rotation of the

For reference, I am using this FP Controller torah horse(.)com(/)First-Person-Drifter-Controller-for-Unity3d-1 (that uses a cylinder, so doesn't have the same rotation issue)

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to put a script on the Camera instead of making it a child of the player. This gives you more freedom in how the Camera behaves.

Actually, looking at your pictures again... Why not just set the Camera behind the player correctly, instead of rotating the player. When you have the Camera as s child it will be responsive to the parents transform, but it wont mimic. It will follow with the same offset as it starts with. So instead of rotating the player, which messes up the controls, simply put the Camera where you want it from the start.